# Could/should a Value Object hold methods relevant only to itself?

Tags: actionscript-3, puremvc

I have a GridVO which can hold numbers. Imagine it is for Sudoku.

There are "pupulateGrid", "testColumn", "testLine", "clone" and several other methods that modify a specific instance of GridVO.

Of course, I have a Proxy which instances and holds that vo.
My question, do these methods need to be in the Proxy and NOT in the vo? Or viceversa? Or it doesn't really matter.

I would use such things in the future for all such cases so its important I get this right from the start.

Comment: Is the Proxy necessary? Does it add anything extra to your vo, or is it just wrapping it? Is it one Proxy per vo? How do objects interact with your vo through the Proxy? Can a vo exist without a Proxy? If not, how is it enforced? You get the idea :) It's hard to give a good answer as a lot of it depends on your architecture. Generally, an object controls its own properties

Comment: It is, there is an abastract one and 3 that extend it but all 3 use the same vo. The mediator tells the proxt to modify that vo. the vo cannot exist without the proxy. vos are created only in commands.